# Inserting Div above other Div's

Tags: jquery

I currently have a form that submits through ajax and when it's successful it puts the information at the top of a list.

My current layout is

```
<div id="projects">
    <div class="project">
         ....
    </div>
    <div class="project">
         ....
    </div>
    ....   
</div>
```

And I do the inserting by

```
var project = $('<div class="project">' +
                      '<div class="name">'+data.title+'</div>' +
                      '<div class="desc">'+data.desc+'</div>' +
                 '</div><hr />').fadeIn(1000, function() { }
                                   );
 $('.project:first-child').before(project);
 $('.project:first-child').highlightFade({color:'#e3e373',speed:4000,iterator:'exponential'});
```

This works fine once there's something in the list, but when there is nothing there it fails (because it can't find a class with project.

How would I go about improving this so it'll work even if there are no projects in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it slightly differently.

First, I would avoid constructing markup that way, at least in parts. If `data.title` contains, say, `<` then it won't be escaped properly. It's better to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for that.

Second, it's faster to create DOM elements rather than insert raw markup. In this case `$("<div>")` is equivalent to `$(document.createElement("div"))`.

Third, use [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) to insert the content. Then you have no issues.

So:

```
$("<div>").addClass("project")
  .appendChild($("<div>").addClass("name").text(data.title))
  .appendChild($("<div>").addClass("desc").text(data.desc));
  .hide().prependTo("#projects").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is my first time using Jquery so I'm still learning the API.